# I have update the quantity and change Stock Availability to instock but quantity not updated

Tags: magento-1.9, quantity, stock-availability

I have update the **quantity** and change **Stock Availability** to **instock** but quantity not updated. It displayed product saved, but quantity not updated.

Comment: Try doing reindex and check again

Comment: I have tried all things clear cache and reindex. Everythings upadted only have issue with inventory(quantity)

Comment: what is the product type ? quantity not updating in admin  or you are checking in frontend ? once try in incognito as well

Comment: it's a simple product. Quantity not updated into admin. Stock Availability is out of stock , so it does not display front-end

Answer (score 0):

Please try once after Full Reindex as well.